# Разбить строку на равные части JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Дана строка любой длины.
Её нужно разбить на равные части и вернуть их в виде массива.
Если в последней части не хватает символов дополнить их точками.

Например в функцию передаётся длина как аргумент - 4 и сама строка.

Input: `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`
Output: `["lore", "m ip", "sum ", "dolo", "r si", "t am", "et.."]`

В последнюю часть попали только 2 буквы, поэтому остаток заполнен точками.

Comment: что значит "равные части"? одинаковой длины?

Comment: приведи пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" => ["lore", "m ip", "sum ", "dolo", "r si", "t am", "et.."]

Comment: почему именно такое разбиение должно быть? а не `lorem `,`ipsum `, `dolor `, `sit am`, `et....`?

Comment: не нужно делить на слова, просто части одинаковой длины

Comment: тут не на слова - части по 6 символов. Все как в задаче

Comment: Окей) да.
Как это сделать?

Comment: что сделать? :-) твой вариант или мой? :) кто должен определять какие именно части должны быть?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, в ответе неверный результат

Comment: части ЛЮБОЙ длины, длина будет передана в функцию как аргумент

Comment: @Максим, если _длина будет передана в функцию_ - то очевидно части уже **НЕ** любой длины.

Comment: Добавь примеры и описание в сам вопрос.

Comment: добавил).......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Разбиваем по заданной длине части.**

```js
const str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
const length = 5; // длина одной части
const pattern = new RegExp(".{1," + length + "}", "ig");
let res = str.match(pattern).map(item => item.padEnd(length, "."));
console.log(res);
```

**Разбиваем по заданному кол-ву частей.**

```js
const str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
const count = 6; // кол-во частей, которые необходимо получить
const length = Math.ceil(str.length / count);
const pattern = new RegExp(".{1," + length + "}", "ig");
let res = str.match(pattern).map(item => item.padEnd(length, "."));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Comment: Буду благодарен за ссылочку на описание этого метода
new RegExp(".{1," + length + "}", "ig");

Comment: @Максим, [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @Grundy да, я видел эту документацию, буду изучать.
Но там нет описания этого параметра "ig"

Comment: @Максим, [есть](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, понял, что они могут вместе использоваться)

Comment: @Максим если этот ответ решил ваш вопрос, пж-та, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть несколько подходов для разбиения строки на равные части.

Например:

1. Дополняем длину строки так, чтобы она без остатка делилась на длину частей
2. в цикле берем соответствующие подстроки

Для дополнения строки до нужной длины,  заполнением недостатка конкретным символом можно воспользоваться методом [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

Для получения подстроки, можно воспользоваться методом [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Количество итераций цикла, соответствует количеству полученных частей.

```js
var str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

function* chunk(str, len) {
  var padded = str.padEnd(Math.ceil(str.length / len) * len, '.');

  for (var i = 0; i < padded.length / len; i++) {
    yield padded.substring(i * len, (i + 1) * len);
  }

}

console.log([...chunk(str, 4)]);
console.log([...chunk(str, 8)]);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Бомба!